# Why Are My Sample Weights Breaking My Neural Network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Please note that I am new to tensorflow, and machine learning in general.

I have a neural network training on a set of imbalanced data, and thus I require different sample weights.

My model is constructed like so:

```
def loss(a1, a2):
    customloss = keras.backend.mean(keras.backend.square((a1 - a2)))
    return customloss

def build_model():
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(101, activation=keras.activations.linear, input_shape=(101,)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(101, activation=keras.activations.linear))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(101))

    optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.00001)

    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae', 'accuracy'])

    return model
```

and I am training it like so:

```
EPOCHS=400
early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20)
model = build_model()
history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1, sample_weight=weights, callbacks=[early_stop])
```

where `weights` is an array of shape `(9171,)`, and `x` and `y` each have shape `(9171,101)`.

If I remove the `sample_weight` argument, the network runs. But with it in place, I get the following error message:

```
Epoch 1/400
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nnotest.py", line 153, in <module>
    history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1, sample_weight=weights, callbacks=[early_stop])
  File "/home/star2/hgc4/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 780, in fit
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "/home/star2/hgc4/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 363, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/home/star2/hgc4/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3292, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "/home/star2/hgc4/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1458, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 32
     [[{{node loss_1/dense_8_loss/weighted_loss/Squeeze}}]]
```

I have my ideas about why this might not be working. I get that it may be trying to parse my 1D array into the default batch size of 32, but I can't understand why. From reading [the documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) it would appear that you can add a 1D array to constitute a 1D mapping from weights to training data, so this should be easy? What am I missing?

Comment: what are your labels? your network outputs a matrix Nx101

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: I mean the shape of your `y.shape`. It should be the same as the network's output shape

Comment: y has shape (9171, 101), as does x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your loss doesn't have samples. You are getting a global mean.

If mean squared error is what you want, compile with `loss='mse'`.

If anything else, don't collapse the batch dimension (axis=0):

```
def loss(true, pred):
    return keras.backend.mean(keras.backend.square(true-pred), axis=-1)
```